# Go back and forward after onbackpressed clicked

Tags: android

I have 2 activities (MainActivity,SecondActivity)

I am starting SecondActivity from MainActivity now the situation is when I click onbackpress it's return to MainActivity without finishing the second activity

How I can go back to the second activity without reinitializing the activity again?

I created foreground service to display a notification and added the flag start UpdateCurrent to the pending intent but this cause that Oncreate recalled

what is the solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding of your issue is correct, you need to try this:

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP  
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
```

And this:

```
Intent int = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
int.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(int);
```

Comment: should i call this onbsackpress from secondactivity ?

Comment: No, it's not working :( it's reload the secondActivity starting from oncreate

Comment: Try this :   MainActivity extends Activity{

Context context;

      oncreate(){
      context = this;
      Intent int = new Intent (context , SecondActivity.class);
      intent.addFlags(Int.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY);

     }
}

Comment: this will not work since I am calling the second activity from notification